# Returning API response rather than data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

I have been staring at this for a while, and finally realized that my code is returning the "200 ok." response instead of the actual data itself, and that is why it won't populate my ionic buttons.  When I am calling the API via postman, and printing it to the console it is showing the data that I need, so I am assuming the issue is somewhere in the .ts files.

Below is my API code:

```
app.get('/getAllProvs', function (req,res) {
    //var id = req.params.id;

    connection.query('SELECT * from Patient', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err){
            var response = [];

            if (rows.length != 0) {
                response.push({'result' : 'success', 'data' : rows});
            } else {
                response.push({'result' : 'error', 'msg' : 'No Results Found'});
            }

            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            //res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(rows));
            res.send(rows);
            console.log(rows);
        } else {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

below is my provider .ts code:

```
export class RestService {

 data1: any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
  }

    getAllProvs(){
        if(this.data1){
            return Promise.resolve(this.data1);
        }
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get('http://lndapp.wpi.edu:5000/getAllProvs')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log("rest-services.ts subscribe");
                this.data1 = data;
                console.log(data);
                resolve(this.data1);
            });
        }); 

    }
}
```

below is my page .ts file:

```
export class AllPatientsPage {
  data1: any;

  constructor(public app: App, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, public restService: RestService){
    this.getAllProvs();
    }
  }
   getAllProvs(){
        this.restService.getAllProvs()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("all-patients.ts data");
            console.log(data);
            this.data1 = data;
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You create array `response` but never use it. Not clear what intention there is. Shouldn't `res.send(rows);` be `res.json(response);`?

Comment: still doesn't solve the issue, the console is printing out fine at the API server.js level

Comment: Then what is `response` for if you don't use it?

Comment: originally I was trying to build an array out of the data, because I needed an array to loop through for ngFor purposes, but the data from the database changed and is now an array anyway

Answer (score 0):

Send a *json* response from your service:

```
res.json(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening during development, it could be because you're using the same url on your front end react website as your server.js site.

Example:
front end running on : localhost:3000
backend listening on : localhost:3000/api

Fix: Change the port numbers.

1. front end running on : localhost:3000
2. backend listening on : localhost:5000/api

Additional help:

3. package.json: add proxy that points to your server: localhost:5000
4. browser: clear your cookies.

Hope this helps.